# '/dev/v4l-subdev1' node not created anymore for 16 MP Arducam with autofocus (IMX519 based) with Rpi 4B

Tags: pi-4, python-3, driver, libcamera

`/dev/v4l-subdev0` and `/dev/v4l-subdev1` nodes used to be created before when booting up the Rpi with the ArduCam plugged in (via MIPI CSI-2 port). Now only `/dev/v4l-subdev0` shows up, and I'm not sure why. This is an issue because I need `/dev/v4l-subdev1` specifically to be able to manually control the focus motors of the camera. Running on raspian lite 64-bit OS, with an XFCE desktop.

Most of the code I am using is [here](https://github.com/ArduCAM/Arducam-Pivariety-V4L2-Driver/tree/master/focus). Specifically I am making use of: `Focuser.py`, and `v4l2_utils.py`, as-is. Then I have a custom script I wrote which makes leverages these two. Here are the most relevant snippets:

```
def main():

    width = 640
    height = 480
    camera_start(width, height)
    os.system('rm /run/shm/test*.jpg') # NECESSARY (not sure why yet)
    time.sleep(2) # let camera warmup
    target = 2000
    print('target (focus): ', target)
    focuser = Focuser('/dev/v4l-subdev1') # get motor control handle
    focuser.set(Focuser.OPT_FOCUS, target)
```

and the `camera_start` function definition:

```
def camera_start(wx,hx):
    print('starting camera')
    global p
    # -n --> without display
    rpistr = "libcamera-vid -t 0 --segment 1 --codec mjpeg -n -o /run/shm/test%06d.jpg --width " + str(wx) + " --height " + str(hx)
    # with display, for debugging (640,480)
    # i.e test manually with: DISPLAY=:0 libcamera-vid -t 0 --segment 1 --codec mjpeg -o /run/shm/test%06d.jpg --width 640 --height 480
    print(rpistr)
    p = subprocess.Popen(rpistr, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
```

Here is the traceback output when I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/fun/pi/scanner/./scan_qr_code.py", line 220, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/fun/pi/scanner/./scan_qr_code.py", line 168, in main
    focuser = Focuser('/dev/v4l-subdev1')
  File "/home/pi/fun/pi/scanner/Focuser.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.fd = open(self.dev, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/v4l-subdev1'
My application is ending!
Exception ignored in: <function Focuser.__del__ at 0x7f7f238670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/fun/scanner/Focuser.py", line 99, in __del__
    if self.fd:
AttributeError: 'Focuser' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

Does anyone know the reasons why this would happen? Why would `/dev/v4l-subdev1` suddenly stop showing up? My best guess at this point is it's a hardware failure of some sort, since I already dealt with ensuring the right driver settings/overlays were setup and haven't made changes to that since. The same code is still working fine on another mirror hardware test rig.

Comment: I would ask the makers of the hard- and software: https://forum.arducam.com

Comment: Hey @Dirk thanks for the advice, made a post on the forum: https://forum.arducam.com/t/dev-v4l-subdev1-node-not-created-anymore-for-16-mp-arducam-with-autofocus-imx519-based-with-rpi-4b/3508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While going through my dmesg logs again, I noticed it said "consider updating imx driver". So I went ahead and tried that that via `./install_pivariety_pkgs.sh -p imx519_kernel_driver_low_speed` and lo and behold, actually seems to be fixed now.

Was able to reproduce the fix on two separate systems.

Funny enough, dmesg logs still suggest updating the driver.. anyway the issue seems resolved as the `/dev/v4l-subdev1` node is being created again.